# object.__new__() takes no parameters

Tags: python

Ok so I made a user-defined class:

```
class Drinker:
        def __init__(self, name, age):
                self.name = name
                self.age = age
        def canYouDrink(self):
                if self.age > 20:
                        print('yes')
                else:
                        print('no')
```

In my command line window, I did:

```
from drinker import Drinker
dan = Drinker("Dan", 21)
```

Then it gave me this `object.__new__() takes no parameters` error message. Did I define my constructor incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure this is *exactly* how you called it? What version of python are you using?

Comment: 3.3 I believe. Yep, exactly how I called it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Try closing and reopening the interactive session to make sure the module is actually getting reloaded. Failing that, make sure the module is being loaded from the correct place (in case you have more than one copy of `drinker.py`).